# Asserting an exception generated by a @propertyname.setter

Tags: python, unit-testing, properties, assert, testcase

### The Source Code

I have a bit of code requiring that I call a property setter to test wether or not locking functionaliy of a class is working (some functions of the class are `async`, requiring that a padlock boolean be set during their execution).    The setter has been written to raise a `RuntimeError` if the lock has been set for the instance.

Here is the code:

```
    @filename.setter
    def filename(self, value):
        if not self.__padlock:
            self.__filename = value
        else:
            self.__events.on_error("data_store is locked.  you should be awaiting safe_unlock if you wish to "
                                  "change the source.")
```

As you can see here, if `self.__padlock` is `True`, a `RuntimeError` is raised.  The issue arises when attempting to assert the setter with python `unittest` .

## The Problem

It appears that `unittest` lacks functionality needed to assert wether or not a property setter raises an exception.

Attempting to use `assertRaises` doesn't obviously work:

```
    # Non-working concept
    self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, my_object.filename, "testfile.txt")
```

## The Question

How does one assert that a class's property setter will raise a given exception in a python `unittest.TestCase` method?

Comment: very nice question: "How does one assert that a class's property setter will raise a given exception in a python unittest.TestCase method?" knowing that  unittest lacks functionality needed to assert weather or not a property setter raises an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to actually *invoke* the setter, via an assignment. This is simple to do, as long as you use `assertRaises` as a context manager.

```
with self.assertRaises(RuntimeError):
    my_object.filename = "testfile.txt"
```

---

If you couldn't do that, you would have to fall back to an explicit `try` statement (which gets tricky, because you need to handle both "no exception" and "exception other than `RuntimeError`" separately.

```
try:
    my_object.filename = "testfile.txt"
except RuntimeError:
    pass
except Exception:
    raise AssertionError("something other than RuntimeError")
else:
    raise AssertionError("no RuntimeError")
```

or (more) explicitly invoke the setter:

```
self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, setattr, myobject, 'filename', 'testfile.txt')
```

or worse, *explicitly* invoke the setter:

```
self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, type(myobject).filename.fset, myobject, 'testfile.txt')
```

In other words, three cheers for context managers!

Comment: Even includes the setattr invocation!  Very complete solution.  Thank you.  :-)

Comment: For those viewing I would definitely not recommend the explicit casting (labeled worse for valid reasons)  implicit with a ``self.assertIsInstance(myobject, MyObjectClass)`` beforehand works dandy.  I went with the (more) solution here, and it works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you using the `with` statement?

Comment: with context is great for checking multiple statements for the same exception.  I'm only in need to check one.  Didn't see needing to use with in a one-off scenario.  Opening a with context is inherently slower than a direct invocation, as well, so its a use-as-needed proposition to me.

Comment: There is an error after doing some tests.  ``DeprecationWarning: callable is None`` .  If using my prefered choice, proper syntax to avoid this warning is ``self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, setattr, myobject, 'filename', 'testfile.txt')``   You must not invoke the callable from within the call to ``assertRaises``, but let the method invoke it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setattr` method like so:

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError, setattr, p, "name", None)
```

In the above example, we will try to set `p.name` equal to `None` and check if there is a `ValueError` raised.